# Is a PREEMPT-ible Linux kernel Real Time?

Tags: raspberry-pi, arm, real-time, cross-compiling

I was configuring `rpi-3.8.y` (raspbian kernel on 3.8.y branch) using `menuconfig` and came across the following,

[image]

Will selecting a PREEMPT-ible kernel (choice #3) cross-compile a real-time  one ?

Comment: Depends what you mean by realtime. What sort of realtime are you looking for?

Comment: *real time* is a loaded concept.  It will attempt to minimize interrupt latency and high priority task delay.  However, it can often minimize work done (Ie CPU through-put) as time is spent context switching instead of doing work.  Do you mean context switch time, interrupt latency, or some other concept?

Comment: @barny soft real time

Comment: @artless_noise I'm only looking at providing an environment for executing soft real time tasks. I don't have a preference over low level implemention details.

Answer (score 1):

No.

The closest thing you'll get to real-time with Linux is PREEMPT_RT, which is an [out-of-tree patch set](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/realtime/start), and clearly not present in whatever kernel sources you're building.

Comment: Then, what is the difference by having a PREEMPTible kernel ?

Comment: You get a more responsive system for interactive use. On a non-interactive server you generally want I/O and other in-kernel operations to complete as soon as possible for maximum throughput, therefore even the overhead of interrupting and immediately continuing them is undesirable; on a desktop machine, though, we generally prefer that e.g. the screen still updates and the mouse cursor still moves during long-running I/O calls.